# Self similar solutions of mean curvature flow and Gaussian curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I want to know if the mean curvature flow has such a relationship ,and if so, what is like?

The solution $F_t$ to the Gaussian curvature flow $\partial_t{F}=-K\nu$ is the self-similar if for some constant $c(t)$ depending only on time, $\nabla (\partial_\tau{F})=c(t)\nabla {F}$,there $\partial_\tau{F}=-K\nu+X$ and X is tangential vector field.

So I want to know if there is a similar relationship for the mean curvature flow equation. Thanks a lot of!

There have another question. If $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative, then why is
$$\partial_t \nabla_i \nabla_j=-\partial_t \Gamma_{ij}^{k} \nabla_k?$$

Comment: "some *constant* $c(t)$ depending only on time" - -what do you mean here?

Comment: I dont understand why there is $\nabla$ in the definition of the self-similat solution. Can you cite a reference?

Comment: @ArcticChar This formula comes from the article "on Harnack inequality and entropy for the Gaussian curvature flow ”

Comment: @fundamentalform I think it's a function that only depends on t

Comment: Okay, i will check the reference later. Let me just say that there are similar definition of self-similar solution in MCF. These include the self-shrinker and self-expander.

Comment: So then it's not a constant....

Comment: @ArcticChar If you know the formula, can you tell me what it is? Or tell me where I can learn it, thank you!

Comment: @fundamentalform Yes, you are right.